# How to hide event URL in print view

Tags: fullcalendar

we are developing with fullcalendar and try to activate the print option for our customer. We use the latest version of fullcalendar and we use event urls to open a lightbox / fancybox after clicking on an event.

But, when it comes to the print view, and to printing for example a week, all the event urls are shown within the events. We really tried everything so far, to hide them from the print view, no success.

[ajax_envent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyqC2.jpg)

[image]

I try to attach a photo. Any ideas or solutions on this?

Kind regards
Mike

Comment: can we please see your event data, and the code where you "tried everything?". What did you try, so I don't have to repeat the experiment when trying to find a solution. I cannot immediately reproduce your problem - see http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/189/

Comment: thanks for the answer. my event data comes from a json file. here is an example. 

[{"id":6767,"title":"Mehrfachblockierung - Damentraining","start":"2018-02-20T15:00:00","end":"2018-02-20T15:45:00","color":"#980000","url":"ajax_edit_event.asp?event_id=6767&rental_dates_key=1e85f6be1e625b0fd27571e3f31c6c8d","editable":true,"event_tooltip_color":"#980000","event_tooltip":"","resourceId":"1"}]


what we tried so far, is hiding the url in the print.css and especially we tried to find others with the same problem. no luck so far.

Comment: the first two things i see is that in your fiddle the url is on the last position in the event data, and that we use resources... maybe this is something we should look a little bit deeper in.

Comment: please add code / data /extra info into the question itself, it's hard to read in in comments, and others may not see it. And also show the actual code you tried so far, not just a description of it. Thanks. P.S. The ordering of properties in a JS object has no effect on anything. If you use resources, again please share the code. We need a reproducible example of your specific circumstances. See  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Although again I doubt if it has much influence.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/239/ shows the fiddle using your event data. Again when you print, there is no problem. P.S. I added the print CSS, which was missing from the previous fiddle - sorry about that. But still, it makes no difference, the URLs are not shown in either the main display or the print output. Perhaps someone has customised your fullCalendar JS or CSS files?